# Give argument php function to show database results in another file

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php code to connect database it works fine.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "cv";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM services";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["service_name"]. " " . $row["service_desc"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

**My question is:** how to create function getServices() and give argument to show this results in another php file using foreach or while, like this:

```
   <?php foreach ($results as $key=>$result) : ?>
     <?php echo $result['service_name']; ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: sorry for my bad english. okey thank you for your answer I will try to connect width mysqli

Comment: No problem! Yes that would be great. I know its a bit annoying... but mysql is no longer supported by PHP. If you're going to upgrade you're PHP version to the newest your whole application won't work anymore. And mysql is also really bad for security reasons.

Comment: I change code :) can u see now?

Comment: First of all: Nice work. You're the first one i've ever seen doing this changes when we recommend. So now you can simply include your DB file in the other file, and thats nearly all. Then you can put your SQL statement in a function and call the function. If you wish i can write you an exmaple.

Comment: Did you find a solution, or you need help? I can write a example if you wish.

Comment: ok, I want to create function getServices and write this code inside this function, but also I want to display function data another file by foreach, of course if this is possible (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So you have to do the following things:

db.php :

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "cv";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

function yourFunctionName() { 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM services";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
return $result;
  }

        $conn->close();
```

otherfile.php :

```
    <?php
       include 'db.php';

    $data = yourFunctionName();

    if ($data->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["service_name"]. " " . $row["service_desc"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
?>
```

Hope this works, haven't tested yet.

Comment: I tested and get this:Notice:  Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\cv\includes\db.php on line 17
Fatal error:Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\cv\includes\db.php on line 17

Comment: I think this is because that database connection is no inside function

Comment: I found solution and it works fine, I write this insede function global $conn;

Comment: Okay thats a possibility... otherwise you can take away the global and just pass it to the funtion with yourFunctionName($conn)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have not reputation yet to vote this answer

Comment: No problem ;) I'm here to help, not for reputation :P 
Hope you have a nice day and feel free to come back if you have another question :D